# Check using the Leibniz test the convergence of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I`m trying to check if the series is convergent.
$$\begin{align}&1)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}\cdot\frac{\ln n}{n}\\
 &2)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}\cdot\frac{n+2}{\sqrt{n+1}}\end{align}$$
what I did on the first series is:
1) take the $|a_n|$ and check if it convergent.

$$ 1)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n+2}{\sqrt{n+1}}<\frac{1}{n^{-0.5}} \rightarrow p=-0.5 < 1 \rightarrow \text{Not convergent}$$
let say P is the Exponent of the harmonic series I chose.
now what? I need to make the two tests? the way I check is right?
for the second series, I need some advice how to check it. 
thanks!

Comment: the demand is to check it with Leibniz test so we have 2 tests, the first one is $lim = 0$ and the second one is check if its Monotonically decreases. fix me if I`m wrong.

Comment: For the absolute convergence in (1) note that $\int \ln(x)/x dx = \ln^2(x)$ and use the Integral test. For Leibniz test you need to show the monotonic convergence of the terms to $0$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

== For any $\,\epsilon>0\,$ we have that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log x}{x^\epsilon}\stackrel{\text{l'Hospital}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1{\epsilon \,x^\epsilon}=0$$

Obtain from the above that $\;\displaystyle{\frac{\log n}{n^\epsilon}}\;$ converges monotonically to zero.

== Using comparison methods (in fact, the following is the squeeze theorem. Why though? ):

$$\frac{n+2}{\sqrt{n+1}}\ge\sqrt{n+1}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty$$

Comment: for your first answer, its not Converges with condition? its just converges?

Comment: Yes, @OfirAttia: it converges conditionally.